# Spring Paging and sorting repository - Custom converter - No converter found capable of converting from type to type

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

I have such **repository**:

```
public interface ApartmentRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Apartment, Long> {

    Page<LandlordPageApartment> findAllByOwnerId(long ownerId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

And when I use it, there is an **exception**: `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [Apartment] to type [LandlordPageApartment]`

Here I define my **converter**:

```
@Component
public class ApartmentToLandlordPageApartmentConverter implements Converter<Apartment, LandlordPageApartment> {

    @Override
    public LandlordPageApartment convert(Apartment apartment) {
        // some conversion
    }

}
```

**Converter registration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AbsWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(apartmentToLandlordPageApartmentConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApartmentToLandlordPageApartmentConverter
    apartmentToLandlordPageApartmentConverter() {
        return new ApartmentToLandlordPageApartmentConverter();
    }
// ...
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Is your converter bean also registered as a `@Component`?

Comment: @Makoto yes, but I think it does not matter.

Comment: Plz post the full stacktrace ... i found [a similar issue here on so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53119756/592355), where (erroneously) `ConverterNotFoundException` pops up instead of something deeper.

Comment: @xerx593 sorry, but "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."